# Setting meta title doesn't work (getMetaTitle() returns null)

Tags: magento-1, meta-title

When I set the meta title, both on product and category, the title in the Header is not changing. Then I tried to manually change the function in the header.php to `getMetaTitle()` but it returns `null` everytime.

What could be the problem?

Comment: have you changed the cache after setting meta title in the backend for the products and category ?

Comment: Of course; the other meta change when I set them, the meta title is the only one that doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any custom modules added in your project which is overriding the core function `getMetaTitle()`. If it is the case, try to modify the code to get the value of meta title. Please post here if this is not the case and still you are facing the issue.

Comment: I have done a `grep -R 'getMetaTitle()' .` but it returns only 3 results in the Magento core;

Comment: Are you saving anything store/website specific and checking in another store/website ?